# PHP OOP - Extending classes

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm quite new to OOP and there are a few things I'd like to ask.

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress using OOP and I want to find out how I can allow other plugin developers to extend and redefine certain functions.

I have the main code wrapped in a class as follows and the class is instantiated at the bottom of the file:

```
class MyPlugin {

    // .. methods here ..

    public function myMethod(){
        // do something
    }

}

$myplugin = new MyPlugin;
```

However, I also want another plugin to be able to rewrite myMethod() by extending the class.

```
class OtherPlugin extends MyPlugin {
    public function myMethod(){
        // do something else
    }
}
```

But in order for `$myplugin->myMethod()` to 'do something else', should I do this to override the `$myplugin` object:

```
$myplugin = new OtherPlugin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would want to reload that variable with the new, modified class... unless you pass by reference. Check it out... [it's a neat little trick](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Happy coding! =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what happens if my object already has properties in it? Wouldn't reloading the variable reset all set properties? And could you explain a little more about passing by reference? I've read the PHP manual and know how it works, but I don't quite get how it can be applied in this situation.

Comment: Unless I'm making some grave mistake in understanding what you're asking, I don't believe there would be a problem. You're running the same class, so everything will be identical apart from the extension. Run a test case yourself, and come back if you have any issues! And by passing by reference, I was simply giving an alternative to explicitly resetting the variable. It's not really important either way for your purposes.